# One function refuses to export, while other functions export?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, asdf, quicklisp

Yesterday, I asked a question about creating libraries with common lisp.

my lib:

```lisp
;in my-lib.asd
(asdf:defsystem :my-lib
  :depends-on (:cl-json :clsql :clsql-sqlite3)
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "functions")
               (:file "macros")))

; in package.lisp
(defpackage :my-lib
  (:import-from :cl-json :encode-json-to-string)
  (:use :cl)
  (:export :use-db
           :make-json
           :cwd
           :status-update))

; in functions.lisp

(in-package :my-lib)

....

(defun make-json (a-list)
  (encode-json-to-string a-list))

(defun change-to-path (project-name)
  (uiop:chdir (merge-pathnames project-name "~/quicklisp/local-projects/")))

(defun cwd ()
  (uiop/os:getcwd))

.....
```

my other project that depends on the library

```lisp
;;in project.asd
(asdf:defsystem :project
  :depends-on (:dexador :clsql :clsql-sqlite3 :my-lib :cl-csv :uiop)

;;in package.lisp

(defpackage :project
  (:shadowing-import-from :cl-csv :read-csv)
  (:use :cl :my-lib))
```

### The problem

I keep getting the error `The symbol "MAKE-JSON" is not external in the MY-LIB package`.

But the other functions that exported work fine. Only make-json doesnt. why?

When i look for all exported packages in the `my-lib` project, i get a list of all functions except `make-json`.

```lisp
> (do-external-symbols (s (find-package 'my-lib))
       (print s))

MY-LIB:STATUS-UPDATE 
MY-LIB:REM-VAR 
MY-LIB:CWD 
MY-LIB:CHANGE-TO-PATH 
NIL
```

UPDATE:

It seems that `make-json` only gets added to the list of exported functions if I manually compile the defpackage for `my-lib`.

I have tried to compile the file with `(asdf:load-asd "my-lib")` but i still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, at least, the problem that your system doesn't have the dependencies it needs: in order, for instance, for `functions.lisp` to be compiled then `package.lisp` needs to have been compiled and loaded.  The art of defining systems is the art of expressing dependencies between their parts.

In this case there is an easy approach and a fancy approach.

**The fancy approach** is to express the dependencies explicitly, for instance by:

```
(defsystem :my-lib
  :depends-on (:cl-json :clsql :clsql-sqlite3)
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "functions"
                :depends-on ("package"))
               (:file "macros"
                :depends-on ("functions"))))
```

**The easy approach** is to tell ASDF that the system has implicit serial dependencies and make sure the components are in the right order:

```
(defsystem :my-lib
  :depends-on (:cl-json :clsql :clsql-sqlite3)
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "functions")
               (:file "macros")))
```